# DynaLoader seeing wrong values in @INC

Tags: perl

I have multiple versions of Perl installed; each under a different directory. e.g. `C:\Perl\5.x.y`. I switch between them in a shell by setting PERL5LIB and altering my PATH so that only one version is visible at a time. Normally, this works fine, but when trying to run the version of `pp` (PAR::Packer) installed under 5.10.1 I have problems loading XS components. parll2nc.exe complains:

> This application has failed to start because perl512.dll was not found...

I set PERL_DL_DEBUG and see the following when DynaLoader initializes:

```
DynaLoader.pm loaded (C:/Perl/5.10.1/site/lib C:/Perl/5.12.1/lib ., \lib)
```

The stuff before the comma is `@INC`. The first entry is correct, the second is *not*. I can't figure out how DynaLoader is getting a 5.12 lib path as running perl directly shows what I would expect:

```
C:\>perl -e "print join ' ', @INC"
C:/Perl/5.10.1/site/lib C:/Perl/5.10.1/lib .
```

How is DynaLoader picking up the wrong path and how do I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Do you see anything hinky in `perl -V`? e.g. in the @INC list there?

Comment: No, `perl -V` shows the same for `@INC`. I suspect it's a PAR::Packer thing as `perl -MText::CSV_XS -e 1` works and DynaLoader emits the right values for `@INC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is caused by an interaction of several things:

- I have *.pl files associated with perl.exe (for the most recent version of Perl installed -- 5.12.1).
- I have ".PL" in my PATHEXT environment variable so that I can run Perl scripts without typing the extension. e.g. `C:\>foo` instead of `C:\>foo.pl`
- My installation of the `pp` utility does not have a batch file wrapper created with `pl2bat`. (I'm not sure why.)

The net result is that when I ran `pp @myconfig` it effectively did this:

```
C:\Perl\5.12.1\bin\perl.exe C:\Perl\5.10.1\site\bin\pp.pl @myconfig
```

i.e. it ran the version of pp.pl in my path using the version of perl associated with *.pl files, *not* the version of perl in my PATH. Thus the mix of libs in `@INC` between what came from the executable (C:\Perl\5.12.1\lib) and what came from the PERL5LIB environment variable (C:\Perl\5.10.1\site\lib).

The solution is to either run `pp` as `perl pp.pl` or (better, because you don't have to remember anything) to create a batch wrapper. Assuming that .BAT is in PATHEXT before .PL, when you type `pp` Windows will run `pp.bat` instead of `pp.pl`, and `pp.bat` invokes `perl` (using the version in your path).

*sigh*

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the approach I suggested for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930965/is-my-perl-script-grabbing-environment-variables-from-someplace-else/2931001#2931001), put a trace on `@INC` and see when it gets updated.

At the very top of your script, before any other `use` statements, put:

```
use Tie::Trace;
BEGIN { Tie::Trace::watch @INC };
```

Then you will get a warning message when another module edits your `@INC` array.

Comment: use this technique with `Carp::Always` and you'll get stack traces and an even more informative message.